# Custom Field query with multiple statements

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress, I want to query ONLY all posts that has `mata_key` "`forside_storrelse`" with value `300 x 339 px (artikel)` OR `615 x 600 px (featured artikel)`.

It should only show the 5 latestest and be sortet by `mata_value_num` which is the value of the meta_key `wpb_post_views_count`.

I can't see whats wrong here below. It dosen't work :(

```
array( 
    'posts_per_page' => 5, 
    'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count', 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'meta_key'      => 'forside_storrelse',
            'meta_value'    => '300 x 339 px (artikel)',
            'meta_compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'meta_key'      => 'forside_storrelse',
            'meta_value'    => '615 x 600 px (featured artikel)',
            'meta_compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Rob Cs edit of my question I figured out what was wrong.

in the `meta_query` array, I need to get rid of "meta_" and just write `key` `value` and `compare`.

Full working code below:

```
array( 
    'posts_per_page' => 5, 
    'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count', 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'forside_storrelse',
            'value' => '300 x 339 px (artikel)',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'forside_storrelse',
            'value' => '615 x 600 px (featured artikel)',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
)
```